# Set permission for static website on Azure Blob Storage

Tags: authentication, azure, storage, blob

I have some static websites hosted on Azure Blob Storage and I want to grant access to those websites only for authenticated users from an ASP.NET MVC application.

I can't have the Blob Storage public.
I think I cannot use Shared Access Signatures taking in consideration that the website uses lots of javascript, css that are downloaded automatically by the main .htm page.

What's the best solution in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If the permissions from your application must be checked then you can build a controler in your application that will act as a proxy between client and blob storage. No Shared Signatures, only regular blob keys on and your regular authentication for users.

The action takes the url relative to your blob as argument. You can add a custom route so is nicely handle links you can make inside your static website.

Comment: I am already using this solution but I would like to skip getting the files through my server and get them directly from Azure Storage.

Comment: Then you should generate shared access signatures. Another option would be to setup a CDN on your hostname and have the authorisation logic implemented there for static files, using Blob as Origin and sending the rest of the traffic to your app.